# Change the fontsize of a particular section title

Tags: sectioning, fontsize

Due to the requirement of format, I need to set the fontsize of the section titles in appendices to 14pt, while in the main body the fontsize of section titles is required to be 16pt.

I use the appendix package for my appendices, so my code is like:

> \usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
>
> \begin{document}
>
> \section{section in the mainbody}
>
> ...
>
> \begin{appendices}
>
> \section{section in appendices}
>
> ...
>
> \end{appendices}
>
> \end{document}

With the fontsize of section titles in the mainbody readily set to be 16pt, how can I change the fontsize of section titles in my appendices environment?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your basic fontsize for the document?

Comment: @Bernard It is 12pt.

Comment: In this case, load `titlesec` and use, just after `\begin{appendices}`, the command `\titleformat*{\section}{\large}`. It should do the trick.

Comment: @Bernard It works; I find that I also need to put a such command before the first section in the mainbody. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome!